# Sitecore CRM Integartion using Data Exchange Connector- Contact Match Logic

Tags: xconnect, data-exchange-framework, crm

We are integrating `CRM` and Sitecore 9.0.2 using **Dynamics Connector 2.0.1**.

As per the default matching logic, The contact id's are matched from two systems to identify a contact. And based on Sitecore contact logic email id is our identifier.

We have a scenario where in a University, we have two contacts who are using same Email ID, i.e. Student and his Parents share an email ID where as they are identifies as different users in a `CRM` system using "First name, Last Name and Email" combination set.

Now the issue is if say a parent fill sin some details in Sitecore system using his child's email during the sync it can be a case the details of Child gets overridden instead of the Parent.

How can we handle this situation ?

Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use custom identifier in Sitecore which is a combination of FN+LN and Email.